# Get events history from a table that holds events and their old versions at the same time

Tags: sql, mysql, input-history

I have a table with events "events" that holds all events and their older versions. I have these columns:

- "id" primary,
- "origin_id" here I keep the ID of the original event,
- "date_added" DATETIME column.

When I first add an event its "origin_id" get its "id" value. When I change this event I create a new event with the same "origin_id" as the first one, new auto-incremented "id" and new "date_added" of course.

How to get a list with all current events from table, without their old versions ordered by the starting date "start" - a DATETIME column again?

So if I have a 3 events and each of them has several revisions/updates I want to get only the last update for each of them.

Comment: I am not sure should I accept my answer, wait for other people to answer and then accept or delete the question?

Comment: The question seems perfectly valid, I don't think it should be deleted. But anyway, no need to worry now, as I'm relieving you of your indecision. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amm I think I got it on my own :)

```
SELECT *
FROM events WHERE id  
IN (
SELECT MAX( id )
FROM events
GROUP BY origin_id
)  
ORDER BY start ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
SELECT MAX(id), origin_id, MAX(date_added), start
FROM events
GROUP BY origin_id, start
ORDER BY start ASC
```

It is certainly not the same as your own solution, so I think you are free to accept yours if mine doesn't work for you and if nothing better turns up.

Comment: Well I have other data in "events" that I would like to fetch so my decision still works better for me event if yours will do the work also. My initial mistake was not using the "id" but the "date_added" only.